# my-default.ini missing in MySQL download

Tags: mysql

I downloaded mysql-5.7.19 for windows. I got all the expected folders and files except my-default.ini (config file). As a next step, I am asked to create my.ini file by copying contents from my-default.ini but my-default.ini is missing in my case.

Comment: If you download the Windows MSI Installer, it will create a default my.ini for you. In my case for 5.7.23, it placed it under c:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.7/my.ini

Comment: When using the latest version (8.0.x): [When using the MySQL Installer to install MySQL Server, it creates the my.ini at the default location, and the user executing MySQL Installer is granted full permissions to this new my.ini file.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/windows-create-option-file.html#:~:text=When%20using%20the%20MySQL%20Installer%20to%20install%20MySQL%20Server%2C%20it%20creates%20the%20my.ini%20at%20the%20default%20location%2C%20and%20the%20user%20executing%20MySQL%20Installer%20is%20granted%20full%20permissions%20to%20this%20new%20my.ini%20file.)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have an `ini` file, then you should look for a `.cnf` file. If you don't have either, then you could choose to [use one of the examples here.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/option-files.html)

Here is an example file:

```sh
[client]
# Which port the client should use as a default.
# this means if you're connecting to the local machine, then you can omit 
# the --port parameter
port=3306

[mysqld]
# Which port you're using. You'll need to write 
# mysql --port=3360 if you're specifying the port
port=3306
# These two have to do with size of data allowed in the system
key_buffer_size=16M
max_allowed_packet=8M

[mysqldump]
# The style of mysqldump to use as default
quick
```

Just for clarity, if you change the `port=3306` to `port=3307` under `[mysqld]` but don't change it under `[mysql]` then you must always use `mysql --port=3307`. On the other hand if you change *both* `port=3306` to `port=3307` you can omit the port parameter.