# Why there is no my-default.ini in MySQL ZIP Archive?

Tags: php, mysql, zip, php-ziparchive

I download MySQL ZIP Archive from here : https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/ (Windows (x86, 64-bit), ZIP Archive)

I have never installed using a zip file. So I follow this tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kJbwKQqwtoE&t=495s

From the youtube tutorial, after extract the zip file, there exist `my-default.ini`

But when I extract the zip file, I don't find the `my-default.ini`

How can I find it?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/option-files.html or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45591412/my-default-ini-missing-in-mysql-download

Comment: @RamRaider, I need a spesific answer

Comment: Is there a `.cnf` file?

Comment: @RamRaider, No. I don't find it

Comment: The tutorial video you linked to instructs you that you need to create the file `my.ini` - have you done so?

Comment: @RamRaider, No. Because `my-default.ini` don't exist. You try to watch the youtube video again. When he open `mysql-5.7.64-winx64` folder, there exist `my-default.ini`

Comment: @RamRaider, If you do not have a solution?

Comment: the only thing I can say is to create your own. I do not know why it does not exist - perhaps address that question on the mysql forums

Comment: @RamRaider, I think I can get an answer from here

Comment: @RamRaider, I read the comment from from youtube video. It says to create mysql.ini. How do I create mysql.ini? Can you give me a detailed answer?

Answer (score 0):

In a basic text editor you could copy and paste one of the example ini files from the links I gave previously or you can copy this to a new, blank text file - save as `my.ini` in the installation directory.

You will need to go through this line by line as there are directory paths and settings that are pertinent to my system and you will need to change them. ( For instance `C:/data/mySQL_Databases` or `c:/wwwroot/certificates/dbcert` )

Use a `#` to comment out a setting or remove if you need to use a setting.

There is plenty of guidance throughout the file so take time to read it.

---

```
# MySQL Server Instance Configuration File
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Generated by the MySQL Server Instance Configuration Wizard
#
#
# Installation Instructions
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# On Linux you can copy this file to /etc/my.cnf to set global options,
# mysql-data-dir/my.cnf to set server-specific options
# (@localstatedir@ for this installation) or to
# ~/.my.cnf to set user-specific options.
#
# On Windows you should keep this file in the installation directory 
# of your server (e.g. C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server X.Y). To
# make sure the server reads the config file use the startup option 
# "--defaults-file". 
#
# To run run the server from the command line, execute this in a 
# command line shell, e.g.
# mysqld --defaults-file="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server X.Y\my.ini"
#
# To install the server as a Windows service manually, execute this in a 
# command line shell, e.g.
# mysqld --install MySQLXY --defaults-file="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server X.Y\my.ini"
#
# And then execute this in a command line shell to start the server, e.g.
# net start MySQLXY
#
#
# Guildlines for editing this file
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# In this file, you can use all long options that the program supports.
# If you want to know the options a program supports, start the program
# with the "--help" option.
#
# More detailed information about the individual options can also be
# found in the manual.
#
#
# CLIENT SECTION
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# The following options will be read by MySQL client applications.
# Note that only client applications shipped by MySQL are guaranteed
# to read this section. If you want your own MySQL client program to
# honor these values, you need to specify it as an option during the
# MySQL client library initialization.
#
[client]

port=3306
#default-character-set=utf8

[mysql]

default-character-set=latin1







# SERVER SECTION
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# The following options will be read by the MySQL Server. Make sure that
# you have installed the server correctly (see above) so it reads this 
# file.
#
[mysqld]

event_scheduler=ON


# The TCP/IP Port the MySQL Server will listen on
port=3306
#default-character-set=utf8

#Path to installation directory. All paths are usually resolved relative to this.
basedir="C:/Program Files (x86)/MySQL/MySQLServer_5.5.8/"

#Path to the database root
#datadir=C:/Program Files (x86)/MySQL/MySQLServer_5.5.8/data/
datadir=C:/data/mySQL_Databases/v5.5.8_myISAM_data/








# The default character set that will be used when a new schema or table is
# created and no character set is defined
character-set-server=latin1

# The default storage engine that will be used when create new tables when
default-storage-engine=innodb

# Set the SQL mode to strict
sql-mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"




# The maximum amount of concurrent sessions the MySQL server will
# allow. One of these connections will be reserved for a user with
# SUPER privileges to allow the administrator to login even if the
# connection limit has been reached.
max_connections=100




# Query cache is used to cache SELECT results and later return them
# without actual executing the same query once again. Having the query
# cache enabled may result in significant speed improvements, if your
# have a lot of identical queries and rarely changing tables. See the
# "Qcache_lowmem_prunes" status variable to check if the current value
# is high enough for your load.
# Note: In case your tables change very often or if your queries are
# textually different every time, the query cache may result in a
# slowdown instead of a performance improvement.
query_cache_size=0




# The number of open tables for all threads. Increasing this value
# increases the number of file descriptors that mysqld requires.
# Therefore you have to make sure to set the amount of open files
# allowed to at least 4096 in the variable "open-files-limit" in
# section [mysqld_safe]
table_cache=256




# Maximum size for internal (in-memory) temporary tables. If a table
# grows larger than this value, it is automatically converted to disk
# based table This limitation is for a single table. There can be many
# of them.
tmp_table_size=35M




# How many threads we should keep in a cache for reuse. When a client
# disconnects, the client's threads are put in the cache if there aren't
# more than thread_cache_size threads from before.  This greatly reduces
# the amount of thread creations needed if you have a lot of new
# connections. (Normally this doesn't give a notable performance
# improvement if you have a good thread implementation.)
thread_cache_size=8






#*** MyISAM Specific options

# The maximum size of the temporary file MySQL is allowed to use while
# recreating the index (during REPAIR, ALTER TABLE or LOAD DATA INFILE.
# If the file-size would be bigger than this, the index will be created
# through the key cache (which is slower).
myisam_max_sort_file_size=100G



# If the temporary file used for fast index creation would be bigger
# than using the key cache by the amount specified here, then prefer the
# key cache method.  This is mainly used to force long character keys in
# large tables to use the slower key cache method to create the index.
myisam_sort_buffer_size=69M



# Size of the Key Buffer, used to cache index blocks for MyISAM tables.
# Do not set it larger than 30% of your available memory, as some memory
# is also required by the OS to cache rows. Even if you're not using
# MyISAM tables, you should still set it to 8-64M as it will also be
# used for internal temporary disk tables.
key_buffer_size=256M



# Size of the buffer used for doing full table scans of MyISAM tables.
# Allocated per thread, if a full scan is needed.
read_buffer_size=64K
read_rnd_buffer_size=256K



# This buffer is allocated when MySQL needs to rebuild the index in
# REPAIR, OPTIMZE, ALTER table statements as well as in LOAD DATA INFILE
# into an empty table. It is allocated per thread so be careful with
# large settings.
sort_buffer_size=256K











#*** INNODB Specific options ***
innodb_data_home_dir="C:/data/mySQL_Databases/v5.5.8_innoDB_datafiles/"



# Use this option if you have a MySQL server with InnoDB support enabled
# but you do not plan to use it. This will save memory and disk space
# and speed up some things.
#skip-innodb



# Additional memory pool that is used by InnoDB to store metadata
# information.  If InnoDB requires more memory for this purpose it will
# start to allocate it from the OS.  As this is fast enough on most
# recent operating systems, you normally do not need to change this
# value. SHOW INNODB STATUS will display the current amount used.
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size=16M



# If set to 1, InnoDB will flush (fsync) the transaction logs to the
# disk at each commit, which offers full ACID behavior. If you are
# willing to compromise this safety, and you are running small
# transactions, you may set this to 0 or 2 to reduce disk I/O to the
# logs. Value 0 means that the log is only written to the log file and
# the log file flushed to disk approximately once per second. Value 2
# means the log is written to the log file at each commit, but the log
# file is only flushed to disk approximately once per second.
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1



# The size of the buffer InnoDB uses for buffering log data. As soon as
# it is full, InnoDB will have to flush it to disk. As it is flushed
# once per second anyway, it does not make sense to have it very large
# (even with long transactions).
innodb_log_buffer_size=2M




# InnoDB, unlike MyISAM, uses a buffer pool to cache both indexes and
# row data. The bigger you set this the less disk I/O is needed to
# access data in tables. On a dedicated database server you may set this
# parameter up to 80% of the machine physical memory size. Do not set it
# too large, though, because competition of the physical memory may
# cause paging in the operating system.  Note that on 32bit systems you
# might be limited to 2-3.5G of user level memory per process, so do not
# set it too high.
innodb_buffer_pool_size=512M



# Size of each log file in a log group. You should set the combined size
# of log files to about 25%-100% of your buffer pool size to avoid
# unneeded buffer pool flush activity on log file overwrite. However,
# note that a larger logfile size will increase the time needed for the
# recovery process.
innodb_log_file_size=54M



# Number of threads allowed inside the InnoDB kernel. The optimal value
# depends highly on the application, hardware as well as the OS
# scheduler properties. A too high value may lead to thread thrashing.
innodb_thread_concurrency=18

#Enable this option only if you would like to use InnoDB tables.
#skip-innodb

#Start without grant tables. This gives all users FULL ACCESS to all tables!
#skip-grant-tables


#Paths to individual datafiles and their sizes.
innodb_data_file_path=ibdata1:10M:autoextend


#The maximum number of active connections for a single user (0 = no limit).
max_user_connections=200


#The number of seconds the server waits for activity on a connection before closing it

connect_timeout=28800

wait_timeout=1500

interactive_timeout=28800

max_allowed_packet = 32M

back_log = 1000


# Enable SSL for the Server #
# PHP must be 5.3.7 or greater to support ssl in pdo #
ssl=Off
ssl-key=c:/wwwroot/certificates/dbcert/server-key.pem
ssl-cert=c:/wwwroot/certificates/dbcert/server-cert.pem
ssl-ca=c:/wwwroot/certificates/dbcert/ca-cert.pem





#Log all queries that have taken more than long_query_time seconds to execute to file.
long_query_time=2

#Logs will be rotated after expire-log-days days
expire_logs_days=5

#Enter a name for the query log file. Otherwise a default name will be used.
#log

#Enter a name for the error log file. Otherwise a default name will be used.
#log-error

#Enter a name for the slow query log. Otherwise a default name will be used.
#log-slow-queries

#Log some not critical warnings to the log file.
log-warnings
```

Comment: I find new error. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48518242/how-can-i-solve-error-innodb-operating-system-error-number-87-in-a-file-oper. I try your answer. But it's the same

Comment: download the installer - make life easier on yourself

Comment: I use windows 10 home 64-bit. I check from here : https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/, there is no 64 bit

Comment: I add this : `innodb_flush_method=normal` in `my.ini`. I get the answer from here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22461872/configuration-of-mysql-server-installation-failed-or-cant-start-the-service

Comment: I want to ask again. When I access database using database gui (I using sqlyog), I must run `mysqld --console` on command promp first. Is there any other way without running it?

Answer (score 0):

in new version i found there is no need create my.ini file, just run initialize and start server then you good to go. but if you prefer create my.ini you can copy-paste this :

```
[mysqld]
basedir="H:/program_files/mysql"
datadir="H:/program_files/mysql/data_dir"
```

actually answer from RamRaider in comment(link) is good, you can follow that.

Comment: I had try it. But it's the same. There still exist error like this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48518242/how-can-i-solve-error-innodb-operating-system-error-number-87-in-a-file-oper/48523033#48523033

Comment: Solved. I add this : `innodb_flush_method=normal` in `my.ini`. I get the answer from here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22461872/configuration-of-mysql-server-installation-failed-or-cant-start-the-service