# How can I solve "[ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 87 in a file operation" on mysql?

Tags: mysql, innodb

When I run : `mysqld --initialize`, on the `DESKTOP-HU2DG1T.err` file exist error like this :

```
2018-01-30T09:35:35.078489Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2018-01-30T09:35:35.332914Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 87 in a file operation.
2018-01-30T09:35:35.334708Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: File .\ib_logfile101: 'aio write' returned OS error 187. Cannot continue operation
2018-01-30T09:35:35.336378Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot continue operation.
```

I'm installing mysql zip file. I follow youtube tutorial from here : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CQmeFT81o_0

How can I solve the error?

Comment: Same error, mine is on a Windows boot camped by a mac book pro, up vote my comment if you are in a similar situation

Answer (score 0):

Try to re-extract your zip file and make sure your setting (path) is correct. I suspect your write privilege in your windows or your path setting is incorrect but maybe wrong.

To few information to me to answer your answer precisely but hope this can answer your question.

Comment: It seems I have set up well. I follow your answer to make `my.ini` like this : `[mysqld]
basedir="C:/Program Files/mysql"
datadir="C:/Program Files/mysql/data_dir"`. But there exist error. I try without `my.ini`. It's the same

Comment: i found this - https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?22,141927,141927#msg-141927 and please read all message. to sum, your error it seem because your disk driver.

Comment: I had solved a few days ago. I add this : `innodb_flush_method=normal` in `my.ini`. I get the answer from here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22461872/configuration-of-mysql-server-installation-failed-or-cant-start-the-service